# Date() don't output the desired answer

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get something like "October 21st, 2019" I want to have the st,rd,th

```
                <?php
                setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_EN");
                date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
                echo strftime("%B %d, %Y");
                ?>
```

According to the manuals, it's "S" but it always outputs something like "October 21S, 2019"

Comment: ```strftime("%B %d, %Y"); ``` outputs the S?

Comment: No, that outputs "October 21, 2019", but if i put the `strftime("%B %dS, %Y"); ` outputs the S

Comment: If i'm not mistaken you may have to use an IF statement to append the suffix based on the day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Correction you can try this function for desired output, this is a workaround to add an extra modifier:

```
function my_strftime ($format, $timestamp)
{
    $format = str_replace('%O', date('S', $timestamp), $format);   
    return strftime($format, $timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've done this and it worked
`echo date('F dS, Y');`